# xfce 4.10 panel broken align

Tags: linux, gentoo, xfce

I've just updated to xfce 4.10 on gentoo. plugins such as datetime, networkmanager and etc was always at the right of the panel. I've tried to find an option such as "align" but no luck. I dont understand at all how to manage this alignment
[image: xfce 4.10 broken align]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was fixed by using the new, more featureful separator in the menu. Just add a separator in the middle there and configure it to "expand". That will push the right side back to where it was before.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the panel, Panel > Panel Preferences… > Items (tab), and after (below) 'Window Buttons' you'll want to add a new 'Separator' item ('+' sign on right), and set its preferences (double-click it) to Style: Transparent (select) and Expand (check box).